# I got wrong answers when solving an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have this expression:

```
 eqn= -(P (d4^6 + d4^4 (-2 d5^2 +          3 (l - z)^2) + 
           d4^2 (d5^4 - 2 d5^2 (l - z)^2 + 3 (l - z)^4) + 
           2 d4 d5^2 Sqrt[-(-d4^2+ (d3-d5)^2 -(l-z)^2) (-d4^2 + (d3 + d5)^2 - (l - z)^2)] (-l + z) + 
           d3^4 (d4 + l - z) (d4 - l + z) - 
           (d5^2 + (l - z)^2) (l - z)^2 (d5 + l - z) (d5 - l + z) - 
           2 d3^2 (d4^4 + d4^2 (d5^2 + (l - z)^2) - d5^2 (l - z)^2 + 
           d4 Sqrt[-(-d4^2 + (d3 - d5)^2 - (l - z)^2) (-d4^2 + (d3 + d5)^2 - (l - z)^2)] (-l + z))));
```

when I tried to solve:

```
   Solve[eqn == 0, z];
```

I got the following results:

```
{{z -> I (d4 - I l)}, 
 {z -> -I (d4 + I l)}, 
 {z -> -Sqrt[d3^2 - d4^2 - 2 d4 d5 - d5^2] + l}, 
 {z ->  Sqrt[d3^2 - d4^2 - 2 d4 d5 - d5^2] + l}, 
 {z -> -Sqrt[d3^2 - d4^2 + 2 d4 d5 - d5^2] + l}, 
 {z ->  Sqrt[d3^2 - d4^2 + 2 d4 d5 - d5^2] + l}, 
 {z -> -Sqrt[-d3^2 - 2 d3 d4 - d4^2 + d5^2] + l}, 
 {z ->  Sqrt[-d3^2 - 2 d3 d4 - d4^2 + d5^2] + l}, 
 {z -> -Sqrt[-d3^2 + 2 d3 d4 - d4^2 + d5^2] + l},
 {z ->  Sqrt[-d3^2 + 2 d3 d4 - d4^2 + d5^2] + l}}
```

But when I wanted to check the previous results, some of them wasn't correct, like this one:

```
FullSimplify[ eqn /. {z -> Sqrt[d3^2 - d4^2 - 2 d4 d5 - d5^2] + l}, 
                      Assumptions -> d3 > 0 && d5 > 0]
(*
 -8 d4 (d3 - d5) d5 (d3 + d5) (-d3^2 + (d4 + d5)^2) P
*)
```

Any help with this ?

Comment: I can see two types of answers to your question. First is how to get it right in this particular case. Second, that I suspect would be of interest to many, is an explanation of what is going on and whether one should be wary of `Solve` in certain (which?) situations.

Comment: If you can explain the Second case, that would be appreciated>

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful, first notice z always appears with l ( el not one right?  ) and do this sub:

```
eqn = eqn /. z-> zprime + l
```

Then get your solutions:

```
soln = Solve[ eqn == 0, zprime]
```

Which as you notice does not make eqn identically zero when each solution is back substituted.

We can see the additional restrictions required using `Reduce`:

```
Off[Reduce::useq]
{#, Simplify[ Reduce[Simplify[eqn  /. #] == 0], 
         Assumptions -> {Element[{d1, d2, d3, d4, d5}, Reals]} ]} & /@ 
         soln  // MatrixForm


(*    {zprime -> -I d4}   d3 + d5 == 0 || d3 == d5 ||
                          d3 >= Abs[d5] || d3 + Abs[d5] <= 0 || 
                          d4 == 0   *)
   ...etc..
```

Using `Reduce` on each  `Solve` result is for some reason *way* faster than using `Reduce` directly on the original equaiton.